# What "traffic flow" would be right in a transparent "squid + dansguardian" pfsense setup?

Tags: squid, pfsense, dansguardian

My thought (I'm not sure if it's right):

1. LAN interface traffic comes into port 80
2. Destination port is redirected to 8080 (dans guardian)
3. dansguardian outputs traffic to port 3128 (Squid)
4. Squid outputs traffic out in WAN interface to port 80

Answer (score 0):

Squid 3 build in pfSense is perfectly possible to use with any ICAP filtering server (see the list at http://www.squid-cache.org/Misc/icap.html). The good thing about ICAP it is a traffic interception and redirection done by Squid itself, you would not need to mess with firewall redirection rules. If I am not mistaken the transparent HTTP/HTTPS filtering may be supported with just several clicks in the web interface of pfSense.

As an example see http://sichent.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/filtering-https-traffic-with-squid-on-pfsense-2-1/.